# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core app with WebDeploy using TeamCity?

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity, webdeploy

I'm having some trouble understanding how to publish an ASP.NET Core application to a server using Webdeploy on TeamCity.

I've installed the dotnet core teamcity plugin and have two build steps:

- dotnet restore (as a command line step, the built in step timesout on nuget)
- dotnet publish src/projectName/projectName.csproj

However I'm confused as to what to do for the third step, which is to publish the result of `dotnet publish` to our server.

Traditionally we'd use MSBuild and target a publish profile, however I'm unsure whether .NET core utilises MSBuild.

I've got a publish profile as part of my solution which works successfully within VS2017.  I've had a look at the TeamCity blog which discusses setting up TeamCity to use .NET Core, and whilst it does mention WebDeploy, it just simply mentions it can be used alongside `dotnet publish` without really explaining how.

Comment: Have you had a chance to read this blog post by teamcity staff https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/ 

there is also this https://medium.com/monkii/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-sites-using-teamcity-or-just-command-line-cf05fdee58f5 post that goes into greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm confused as to what to do for the third step, which is to publish the result of dotnet publish to our server.
>
> Traditionally we'd use MSBuild and target a publish profile, however I'm unsure whether .NET core utilises MSBuild.

I've also found documentation on automated .NET Core deployment lacking. Generally for deploying to IIS you have two options.

You can still use MSBuild with `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` to deploy a .pubxml publish profile created in Visual Studio as with .NET framework sites. Run MSBuild after dotnet restore and instead of dotnet publish.

Or you can also use dotnet publish to publish to a folder, and msdeploy.exe to sync that folder to an IIS site, possibly on a remote machine. Typically:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="<the folder published to by dotnet publish>"  -dest:contentPath=<Your IIS Site>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've using the next command to create web deploy package:

```
dotnet publish <Path_and_name_of_project>.csproj --configuration Release /p:PublishProfile=<profile_name>
```

and after this step, i've deploy package to iis via webdeploy command